# Laravel/phpunit test with JSON request loses important request details

Tags: laravel, phpunit, lumen, laravel-passport

I have a simple test where I want to assert a particular JSON response. The test (trimmed) looks like this:

```
$response = $this->json('POST', '/api/auth/register', [
        'client_id' => $client->id,
        'client_secret' => $client->secret
    ]);

$response->assertStatus(422);

$response->assertJson([
        'error' => 'validation_error',
        'message' => 'There were validation errors with the form input.'
    ]);
```

Pretty basic stuff. Where things go wrong is that in my app I have a switch that conditionally loads a different exception handler based on the URL. This looks like this:

```
if(request()->is('api/*')) {
    return new Optimus\Heimdal\ExceptionHandler($app);
}
```

If I run the request in curl or postman, no issue. But, in PHP unit it doesn't pick up on the path, it's as iff the path is not being passed over. As an attempt to fix this, I replaced this path check with a check for `wantsJson()` but this doesn't work either.

This seems related to this https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/55 - I have not yet derived a solution though!

I'd like to at least better understand this. A proper solution is preferable, otherwise I can see a dirty hack coming on that future me will probably forget about!

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully appreciate the reasons for why the request isn't available at this point, but a more reliable way of using two handlers is to tie the app's exception handler to optimus rather than swap between them.

The request is passed into `render` and `report` should probably report everything anyway.

The problem I ran into using `$app->runningInConsole()` was that it would cause different handling of web exceptions in tests - e.g. the unauthenticated exception is often caught to trigger redirects via web but not api.

```
/**
 * Create a new exception handler instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container  $container
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Container $container)
{
    parent::__construct($container);

    $this->heimdal = new \Optimus\Heimdal\ExceptionHandler($container);
}

/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return void
 */
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    $this->heimdal->report($exception);

    parent::report($exception);
}

/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($request->is('api/*')) {
        return $this->heimdal->render($request, $exception);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a bit more digging and it seems related to this https://laravel-news.com/request-object-changes-in-lumen-5-4

I moved my conditional code out in to two separate code blocks in the respective route files. This works, but feels nasty changing the environment here. The 'hack' I've opted for for the time being is to add a check for:

```
$app->runningInConsole()
```

This fixes the tests. Feels unsatisfactory, but if it's removed all the tests will blow up and I'll catch it so it will do I guess.